# Django pass empty parameter

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm trying to pass an empty parameter to render a template but I can not achieve this I do not know if the problem is in urls.py or views, I really appreciate a hand.

Urls

```
url(r'^hola/(\b[a-z\.-]+)$', views.hola, name='hola'),
```

Views

```
def hola(request, varr = ''):
    #val = val
    pregunta = Datos_usuario_DB.objects.all().order_by('-id').filter(activo="1")[:15]
    plantilla = {'': 'index.html', 'nosotros': 'nosotros.html'}
    return render(request, plantilla['%s' % varr], {'pregunta': pregunta})
```

When I access to hola/ it says that the website does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

If you want `/hola/` to work, it's easy to add another URL pattern:

```
url(r'^hola/$', views.hola, name='hola'),
url(r'^hola/([a-z\.-]+)$', views.hola, name='hola'),
```

It's not clear to me why you have `\b` in the regex, so I removed it.

Comment: but hola, takes two arguments, so how can I access to hola/?, whit hola/nosotros works fine

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Your second argument `varr` has a default, so if you add the URL pattern for `r'^hola/$` as I suggested, then you can access `/hola/`.

Answer (score 1):

your urls is not contains `hola/` entry, so It returns error.
If you want to call `hola/`, you need to add url in urls.py